# Squared numbers in loop output

Tags: c++

I have this code here that should output all squared numbers before n. For example, if you type `10`, it will show `1 4 9`. The problem is, when I input 25, it should've given output `1 4 9 16 25`. But, instead, it shows `1 4 9 16 24`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>

  int main(){
    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
      {
        b = pow(i,2);
        if (b <= a) cout << b << " ";
      }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `pow` function because it is for floating point.  Instead try `b = i * i;`.  The latter is more efficient also.

Comment: Your issue stems from conversion from integer to floating point and then floating point to integer.  Try this:  `double d = 5.0 * 5.0; std::cout << d << "\n";`.

Comment: Use [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) instead of plain `pow()`, the former has overloads for integers. The floating point version will result a floating point answer, which might not be precisely equivalent to 25. If it is just a tiny bit smaller, the conversion from floating point to integer will round it down to 24.

Comment: Side note: if `b` is greater than `a` - you should break out of the loop

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvLDoMgFET3fMXEbiDapDXpCvVfENHepIBBTBfGb7dU@9jcyZk5V4/jedB6207k9GPuDCryUwxG2YbNE7kBTlkzjUobTLGT7C9qq@K9YQwgF2EVOS6WRAerAq3cSZND00Ad1PvA3zuhxlWmqOo0gfJc7DuwfBJokzP6J6eiFPLXUg/e7m8C2s8RVZXMdDJkX2tlCCbOweEi2bpt5e0F "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Rather than `i <= a;` to test when code should break out of the loop, consider `i <= a/i;` - it does not overflow when `i > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

if you only use integers, and squared numbers you don't need any math library for the solution, you can get the square of a number by multiplying it to itself.

And you can have better performance if you break out of the loop when you reach the first square number that is bigger than your input number, no need to calculate any more.

example code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    for (int b, i = 1;; ++i)
    {
        b = i * i;
        if (b > a)
            break;
        std::cout << b << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely caused by the pow() function. While I was not able to reproduce this error (cmath in MinGW and Visual C++ uses std::pow that has integer overloads since C++98), I believe Your compiler uses the float overload for some reason. You should try replacing `b = pow(i,2)` with `b = i * i`.